# MSIX Deployment via Powershell isnt working

Tags: powershell, deployment, msix, appinstaller

I have 2 PCs here and I want to be able to deploy msix packages using powershell on both PCs.

I tested the whole thing on one PC and it worked. I just used this command:

```sh
add-apppackage -path "enter_path"
```

But when I tried the same thing on the other PC it didnt work. The error I get is the following:

> Add-AppPackage : Deployment failed. HRESULT: 0x80073CF0, The package
> could not be opened. Error 0x80096005: Error opening package in
> location...

I've searched for solutions for a while but nothing seems to be working. Here is a list of what I've tried:

- run powershell as administrator
- sign the package a second time
- trying different packages even one that I didn't create
- uninstalling windows 10 + installing it again

Any help would be awesome thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with the MSIX Packaging tool. This error is caused by the timestamp server you are using. I am not sure what exactly causes the issue but the tool seems to go ahead and signs the package using whatever response it got from the URL, but the signature itself is not valid for an unknown reason. When the installer attempts to install the package and verify the signatures, it fails.
I tried several servers on ths list here:

https://gist.github.com/Manouchehri/fd754e402d98430243455713efada710

Using http://timestamp.sectigo.com took away the error